# How to use shortcut key for Ribbon with Alt+GI and Alt+G?

Tags: windows-10, ribbon

How to use shortcut key for Ribbon with Alt+GI and Alt+G?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can. This is probably a mistake by the developer. AFAIK, shortcut keys on Ribbons should not overlap. Meaning, you can have `GX` and `GY` but never `G` and `GX`.

Comment: You are true...